# Is there a name for vector $u$ such that $\langle v,u \rangle = 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

My question mainly concerns vectors over $\mathbb R^n$ using the euclidean inner product.

We might call $u = v^{-1} = (1/v_1, 1/v_2, \dots, 1/v_n)$ or something like this. The term "multiplicative inverse" comes to mind but since

- $\mathbb R^n$ in general isn't an algebraic ring
- $u$ is not unique
- the result of the scalar product is not a vector
- there is no "identity vector".

it does not seem appropriate.

Would it be OK to say "vector inverse"(s)? Is there another name?

Comment: If $n>1$ then $u$ is not unique so "defined" like this $v^{-1}$ is not well-defined.

Comment: @drhab Ah, true. How about a name for the set of all those $u$ then perhaps?

Comment: Well, it is $\frac{v}{\langle v,v\rangle}+(\operatorname{Span}v)^\perp$. I don't know if this specific presentation of said affine hyperplane evokes some name.

Comment: Mwwah... I don't know a name for that set, and also I fail to see that it is a set that really  "deserves" a name (possibly because my scope is too small on this).

Comment: A basis $(v_1, \dots, v_k)$ where $\langle v_i, v_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$ is called a orthonormal basis, so you could say that $u$ is "orthonormal" to $v$. I never heard anyone using this though.

Comment: Your $v^{-1}$ is not well defined for, say, $v = (1,0)$. Still, $u = (1,x)$ for any $x$ will give $\langle v, u\rangle = 1$. Also, $\langle v, v^{-1}\rangle = v_1\cdot 1/v_1 +\ldots +v_n\cdot 1/v_n = n$.

Comment: In [geometric algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra), a non-zero vector does have an inverse with respect to the *geometric* product. It's essentially the formula G. Sassatelli gives except the outer product aspect of the geometric product excludes components in $(\text{Span}\,v)^{\bot}$. That is, $v^{-1}= v/v^2 = v / \langle v, v\rangle$. Of course, the geometric product is not the inner product and so $uv\neq\langle u,v \rangle$ in general (or even typically). In particular, $uv=\langle u,v\rangle + u\wedge v$.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$ is still a ring. That would be the inverse of the element. This runs somehow parallel to the Euclidean structure of $\mathbb{R}^n$.